# How would I make an if statement with a dictionary/list

Tags: python, list, if-statement, dictionary

My code:

```
hello = ['hi',]  
i=input("> ")
if i==hello:
    print("hi")
else:
    print("no")
```

I wanted to do this for making a text-based game, so the user can enter almost anything similar to what is needed to move on; it does not have to be a list or a dictionary, just something that would work.

Comment: I added the code but it did not come out correctly for some strange reason:

Comment: @SwogadonKellohorMonzi, I think using `hello` as a variable name tripped some kind of filter in StackOverflow, I'm logging a bug.

Comment: Don't start your post with `hello = `, the greetings filter automatically removes that. Put a new sentence *before* your code. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209176/code-that-starts-with-a-variable-named-hello-gets-dropped as well.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you would like to use `in`:

```
hello = ["hi there", "hello", "hey"]
i=input("> ")
if i in hello:
    print("hi")
else:
    print("no")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
hello = set(['hi', 'hello'])
if i in hello:
    # ...
```